# Функция для проверки любых измениний ViewController class

Tags: xcode, swift, mobile-development

Здравствуйте! Существуют несколько UIViewController`ов со множеством textField и pickerView. Существует ли функция, которая отслеживает ЛЮБЫЕ изменения в классе. То есть изменение текса в любом одном textField или же строки в pickerView. Просто я представляю размер метода для сравнения всех этих значений через if например...

Comment: Нет такой. А зачем?

Comment: у вас есть делегаты для всего, можете еще KVO прицепить. Этого вам должно хватить, чтобы отслеживать любые изменения

Comment: Не очень понял как это делать... Я хочу к barButton привязать alertController, что бы он вылетал, когда пользователь не сохранил данные, если внес изменения.

Answer (score 0):

Для таких целей есть делегат. Например [UITextFiledDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uitextfielddelegate).

Данный делегат предоставляет вам множество возможностей, как отслеживать изменения. Например метод `func textFieldDidEndEditing(UITextField)` вызывается когда пользователь закончил вводить текст. Метод

```
func textField(UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn: NSRange, replacementString: String)
```

вызывается когда пользователь вводит текст (работа в этом методе выполнится до того, как введенный текст отобразится в поле). Ну и множество других методов, изучить их можете прочитав документацию.

Пример:

```
func textFieldDidEndEditing(textField: UITextField) {
  if textField == emailTextField {
    // тут будет некое действие если вы только что закончили вводить текст в emailTextField.
   }
}
```

Если у Вас много `textfield'ов` можно использовать switch. Но это другая тема для размышления =)